# SharePoint online Column Empty Item Count

Tags: calculated-column, list-item, item, count

I have a rather large list and I need to count items in  a couple of the columns.

For example:

column1 is [open date] column2 is [closed date]. Both of these are date columns.

Column1 has all the days filled in. Column2 is missing days I want to count the number of blank entries in column2. In another column I want to print that number.